# Getting python scripts to run in http simple server

Tags: python, linux, server

I have a simple python script that I want to serve as a website:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I'm in that folder and run

```
$ python3 -m http.server
```

then I visit
http://hassbian.local:8000/song.py

The terminal says this and I get the file as a txt file, the script won't execute.

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
192.168.1.115 - - [04/Jun/2017 14:19:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.115 - - [04/Jun/2017 14:20:04] "GET /song.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Running on a rasberry pi

Comment: You cannot execute scripts like this. `python3 -m http.server` will simply serve files from the directory on which you ran it.

Comment: what should I use instead?

Comment: It doesn't really have to be python, any simple scripting language is fine by me.

Comment: Probably simplest to do a basic [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) application.

Comment: What do you want to do? You want to build a website or something else?

Comment: If you want `http.server` to serve CGI scripts you need to call it like this: `python3 -m http.server --cgi`.

Comment: @Sraw I'm building a small webservice that takes the names of a coulple of files and outputs their names as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.cgi_directories) doesn't do CGI. If you want CGI you will have to use [CGIHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.cgi_directories)

> This module can run CGI scripts on Unix and Windows systems.

I am not sure if that's what you really want, but invoking a python script in the manner you have shown is CGI. CGI is a really old way of doing things. Running simple web apps with python is now almost exclusively the domain of webapp2 or [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). While more complex apps involving databases are dominated by django.

Comment: great info, cgi seems nice since it's already running on my rasberry pi, I'm creating a small webservice that will serve a couple of files in a folder as a json-object, would cgi be enough?

Comment: Well if it's just json, SimpleHTTPServer is fine. Your question showed you trying to run a python file.

Comment: Well, it's a dynamically created json file, based on the contents of a folder.